Unable to pull latest library from GH packages
Unable to pull latest library from GitHub Packages.
project-commons has 1.10, 1.11, we publish 1.12
If project-service has the following snippet in the build.gradle it still doesn't pull the latest library 1.12 automatically.
project-service
    snippet from build.gradle has
    implementation 'com.company.project:project-commons:+'

